# How does sbt choose which Scala version to use?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have multiple projects in my sbt build. I'm trying to upgrade to Scala 2.10 from 2.9.1, so in my build.sbt file I put

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
```

This seemed to work, because in my top-level project in sbt I get:

```
> scala-version
[info] 2.10.0
```

However, when I switch to one of the other projects:

```
> project web-client
[info] Set current project to web-client (in build file:/C:/Users/...
[web-client] $ scala-version
[info] 2.9.1
```

You see the version has now changed back to 2.9.1! How do I force the same Scala version to be used across all my projects?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found out scoping the scalaVersion to ThisBuild will set it for all sub-projects. Details are here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html at the bottom, but here is what it says:

To set it only once, it is enough to write, in the main build.sbt file, the following line:

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.10.0"
```

Answer (score 6):

SBT has a default Scala version. You need to add the `scalaVersion` setting to all subprojects if you wish to change it. The most common way of doing that is having a "common settings" value that is added to all projects at the root level, through `project/Build.scala`.

Comment: Can I change SBT's default Scala version?

Comment: Also, if I specify the scalaVersion in the plugins.sbt file, which project does it apply to?

Comment: Haven't he just said how to have the same version across all projects?

Comment: I took his answer to mean you specify a version setting, and all the project definitions have references to the same version setting.