# Could not download scala-library-2.11

Tags: java, scala, maven

When I use sbt the error message appears as below:

```
==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11/scala-library-2.11.pom
[warn] ==== bintray-spark-jobserver-maven: tried
[warn]   https://dl.bintray.com/spark-jobserver/maven/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11/scala-library-2.11.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11/scala-library-2.11.pom
```

It seems the "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11/scala-library-2.11.pom" could not be found, and I check the page also does not exist.

It also causes the scala-library-2.11 jar to not be found.

On the other hand, when I check https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/**2.11.0**/scala-library-**2.11.0**.pom this url exists.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Show your `build.sbt` please

Comment: Yup, `build.sbt` would help, probably small detail like `scalaVersion := "2.11"` instead of `scalaVersion := "2.11.0"`, but without the code it is hard to tell.

Comment: Is this resolved, I am facing the same issue. If I put it as 2.11 it is causing issue in downloading scala-library but if I put it as 2.11.0 it is causing issue for other transitive dependent libraries like json4s etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact problem, I eventually figured that there isn't a 2.11 version of scala, and that it isn't equivalent to the 2.11.0 version, check all scala versions available in this [link](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html)

so the steps to fix this are:

1. Change the version into another valid version (2.11.0 for example)
2. delete your `~/.ivy2` directory just to make sure you're starting
   clean and avoid binary conflicts(you can skip this step)
3. re-build your project

and it should work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your scala version to `2.11.12` (or whatever minor version you want, but you need to specify all three parts, as in `2.11.12` or `2.11.8` etc).

### How to Change Your Scala Version

**There are two ways you can do this.**

1. You can do this from build.sbt directly by putting this in your file:

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
```

2. You can also do this from the sbt console.

Open the sbt console:

```
sbt
```

Wait for it to start up, then set the version in the console by running the following:

```
sbt:my-project> ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
```

This sets the version in the console but will not persist beyond this console session. To save this setting, run:

```
sbt:my-project> session save
```

This will save it to your `build.sbt` file for you.

**Note:** if you don't want to set the `scalaVersion` for all subprojects as well, don't scope the `scalaVersion` to `ThisBuild`; [see here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14572148/6952495).

### Update your packages

Now you can update your packages by running:

```
sbt:my-project> update
```

You should see something like:

```
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 10, 2020 5:19:31 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. Earlier, I was trying to shift burden to runtime to provide the dependency - but that's dodging the problem.

Finally, the issue was a transitive dependency relying on scalaVersion (or Scala.version) property specified in my project pom or sbt file.

After changing that to my expectations (2.11.8 specifically), things worked like charm.